# disable rake task on staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rake task, which is started every hour using whenever gem. I want to disable it on staging server, but the obvious way to solve this problem using `if` statement doesn't work somehow. My code is:

```
namespace :checks do
  task test_visible_response: :environment do
    if Rails.env.production?
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

and I execute it like this:

```
every "0 7-21/1 * * *" do
  rake 'checks:test_visible_response'
end
```

PS: It seems I also have a problem with my cron syntax. I want the task to be executed every hour from 7:00 till 21:59, but it works 24/7.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that checking `Rails.env.production?` didn't work (that would have been my suggestion).  It's kind of scary, since it suggests that `whenever` could be running the rake task under the production environment somehow.  Might want to try printing out `Rails.env` and `ENV['RAILS_ENV']` in the rake task just to see what you get?

Comment: The problem has been found. Environment was hardcoded for some reason. So the first part of my question is answered. Now I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with cron.

Comment: it was not hardcoded, it was most likely just set :) see my edit for your cron thing

Comment: After environment variable value had beed changed cron tasks started to work as expected. Everything is alright now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been found. Environment was hardcoded for some reason. So the first part of my question is answered. Now I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with cron.

After environment variable value had beed changed cron tasks started to work as expected. Everything is alright now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the env in `schedule.rb` using `@environment` variable:

```
every "10 7-21 * * *" do
  rake 'checks:test_visible_response' if @environment == 'production'
end
```